# print the words which are delimited using _

Tags: linux

I have a file which is having inputs like

```
a_b a a a 
c a bb_d a
```

I need to print all words which are delimited using `_`. Can anyone please help me out? I tried various awk and sed examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can use grep for this:

```
egrep -o '\b[a-z]+_[a-z]+\b' file
```

Comment: @Shiv than you might want to accept my answer as solution. See more here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

If first column matches regex /_/ print first field. In one liners statements are separetad by semicolons. And then we continue in the same way if third column matches regex print third field.

```
awk '$1~/_/{print $1};$3~/_/{print $3}' file 
a_b
bb_d
```

Comment: Please, add more info to your answer.